# Simultaneous reductions of elliptic curves: same number of points $|E(\Bbb F_p)| = |E'(\Bbb F_p)|$ for some prime $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

$ 
\newcommand{\End}{\mathrm{End}}
\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}
\newcommand{\kb}{\overline{k}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
$

> Let $E,E'$ be two elliptic curves over $\Q$. Is there at least one prime number $p \geq 5$ of good reduction for $E,E'$ such that $|E(\F_p)| = |E'(\F_p)|$ ?

If $E,E'$ are isogenous over $\Q$, this is clearly true. In any case, [François Charles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2914.pdf) proved that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that the reductions of $E,E'$ mod $p$ are isogenous over $\overline{\F_p}$. If the result holds over $\F_p$, we are done.

For instance, for the curves $y^2 = x^{3} - 3 x - 3,  y^2 = x^{3} + x + 6$, the smallest such prime is $p = 3121$.

One could ask if the above question can be generalized to arbitrary smooth projective irreducible curves $C,C'$ (not necessarily of the same genus!) over $\Q$, or even over a number field $K$ (though the heuristic only works well if the primes $\mathfrak{p}$ are totally split over $\Q$, or at least have degree $f \leq 2$).

---

Using ideas from [there](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3371), one can show that if $E,E'$ are not isogenous over $\overline{\Q}$, then the set of such primes has density $0$. According to Lang--Trotter heuristics, one should expect the number of such primes $p<X$ to be $\sim c \sqrt{x} / \log(x)$ for some $c \geq 0$ (if $c \neq 0$, this should give *infinitely many* such primes).

Note: in [his talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Svvyq4166o), he mentions that he doesn't know what happens for *three* elliptic curves, nor what happens over $\F_p$ instead of $\overline{\F_p}$.
For four (or more) elliptic curves, one should *not* expect infinitely many primes such that $|E_i(\F_p)|$ are all equal when $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

Comment: If he doesn't know then I don't think anyone else knows either. (Although I guess there could be something knew since that paper was written.)

Comment: Yes, maybe, but F. Charles was focusing on having _infinitely many_ primes with that property. However, asking the mere _existence_ might be as difficult...

Comment: Indeed it is. If there were only finitely many such primes, quadratic twist both elliptic curves by an extension ramified at those primes, and then there would be none.